# JavaFX ColorPicker Custom color chooser shows behind window

Tags: java, javafx

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("B2B");

    final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorPicker.setValue(Color.RED);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setMinWidth(1000);
    borderPane.setMinHeight(600);
    borderPane.setBottom(colorPicker); 

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

So this is main code. When I click colorPicker and Custom Color that Custom Color window shows behind app window. When I put colorPicker on top or right in borderPane it even doesn't shows up anywhere. Is there some way to force it in the middle on top of main app window or something?

Comment: Post the JDK you are using and your OS. I can't reproduce your issue, and there are no open bugs filed for such an issue.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issues in any of the ways you talk about also how can you tell it is behind the main app mine disappears when i click off of the window